# How to restrict user to upload only three images in a month using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, date

I am working on PHP.  My question is How can restrict a user can upload only three images in a month.

My Mysql Database table --

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` int(40) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` longblob NOT NULL,
  `position` int(40) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want a user can upload only three images in the month.

Kindly help me with the PHP script . I am a beginer in PHP . Share best solution ..

I use this --

```
<?php  
include("admin/config.php");

 if(isset($_POST["insert"]))  
 {  
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
               $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];

$fileinfo = @getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    $width = $fileinfo[0];
    $height = $fileinfo[1];
     $allowed_image_extension = array(
        "png",
        "jpg",
        "jpeg"
    );
    $file_extension = pathinfo($_FILES["image"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

     $sql="select * from images where (name='$name');";

       $count=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);



        $count=count($_FILES['name']);
if($count>3)
{
echo "<font color='red'>3 image upload </font>";
       } else{  



    $file_extension = pathinfo($_FILES["image"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);



         if (! file_exists($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])) {
        $response = array(
            "type" => "error",
            "message" => "Choose image file to upload."
        );
    }   
    else if (! in_array($file_extension, $allowed_image_extension)) {
        $response = array(
            "type" => "error",
            "message" => "<font color='red'>Upload valiid images. Only PNG and JPEG are allowed.</font>"
        );
        echo $result;
    }    // Validate image file size
    else if (($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 2000000)) {
        $response = array(
            "type" => "error",
            "message" => "Image size exceeds 2MB"
        );
    }    // Validate image file dimension
    else if ($width > "1250" || $height > "720") {
        $response = array(
            "type" => "error",
            "message" => "<font color='red'>Image dimension should be within 1250X720</font>"
        );



    } else {


             $target = '/image';
        $target = "image/" . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        $file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));  


      $query =  mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO images VALUES ('','$user_name','$mobile','$email','$file','',NOW())");  

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target)) {
            $response = array(
                "type" => "success",
                "message" => '<font color="green">Image uploaded successfully </font>'
            );

 } else {
            $response = array(
                "type" => "error",
                "message" => "<font color='red'>Problem in uploading image files.</font>"
            );
        }
    }



      // if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))  
      // {  
           // echo '<script>alert("Image Inserted into Database")</script>';  
      // } 
       }      

   }
 ?>
```

And my HTML form -

```
 <form method="post"  id="frm-image-upload" action="my-account.php#parentHorizontalTab3" name='img'
        method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                <div class="agileits_w3layouts_contact_left"style="margin-left:20%;">
                             <input type="hidden" name="user_name" value="<?php  $space = " ";
                             echo $row["fname"].$space.$row["lname"]; ?>"  id="user_name" Placeholder="Your Name"  required /> 
                               <input type="hidden" name="mobile" value="<?php echo $row["mobile"]; ?>" id="mobile"Placeholder="Mobile" required /> 
                              <input type="hidden" name="email"  value="<?php echo $row["email"]; ?>"  id="email" Placeholder="Email"  required/> 
                                             </div>

                           <center>              
                     <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />  
                     </center>
                     <br />  
                     <center><input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Upload" class="btn btn-info" />  </center>
                </form>
```

Please help me share best solution -- A user can upload three images in a month .

Comment: From Review: Please avoid using informality and terms like "I am in critical condition" or "Please help me" in your question. You should concentrate in better explaining the behavior of your source code instead. Please refer to: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection - if this is `"critical"` then I'd suggest looking at these vulnerabilities too as they are more serious

Comment: I remove critical .... I am a beginner in PHP can you please solve this problem... Kindly use my PHP script and give me the best solution

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to count all images uploaded in the given month by given user, like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `images` WHERE `user_name` = ? GROUP BY MONTH(`date`);
```

If the query above returns `3`, you can prevent the upload.

Comment: Can you please solve this using my PHP script. I am a beginner. Please solve using MY script.

Answer (score 1):

@fabrik solution is the simplest approach, but it has a cave-eat of performance decay when dealing with a lot of images/users.

If you dont mind to dig a bit more into the solution, I would suggest adding `image_upload_credit` field to user table. Every time user uploads the image you would reduce the credit by 1.

Since you already have access to `User` object at the time of upload (or should have), the complexity of insert is `O(1)`.

To finish up the solution you need to write a `cron` (periodically run) task which resets the `image_upload_credit` on the first day of each month with `UPDATE user SET image_upload_credit = 3 WHERE image_upload_credit <> 3;`

Comment: I don't get it. Kindly elaborate using my code and post in the comment...Solve it please

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,user_id INT NOT NULL
,date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (user_id,date)
SELECT 1
     , '2018-01-01'
  FROM (SELECT 1) x
  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT user_id
             , DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') ym
          FROM my_table
         GROUP
            BY user_id
             , ym
        HAVING COUNT(*) >=3
       ) y
    ON y.user_id = 1
   AND y.ym = DATE_FORMAT('2018-01-01','%Y-%m')
 WHERE y.user_id IS NULL;
 LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | date       |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2018-01-01 |
+----+---------+------------+

INSERT INTO my_table (user_id,date)
SELECT 1
     , '2018-01-02'
  FROM (SELECT 1) x
  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT user_id
             , DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') ym
          FROM my_table
         GROUP
            BY user_id
             , ym
        HAVING COUNT(*) >=3
       ) y
    ON y.user_id = 1
   AND y.ym = DATE_FORMAT('2018-01-02','%Y-%m')
 WHERE y.user_id IS NULL
 LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | date       |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2018-01-01 |
|  2 |       1 | 2018-01-02 |
+----+---------+------------+

INSERT INTO my_table (user_id,date)
SELECT 1
     , '2018-01-02'
  FROM (SELECT 1) x
  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT user_id
             , DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') ym
          FROM my_table
         GROUP
            BY user_id
             , ym
        HAVING COUNT(*) >=3
       ) y
    ON y.user_id = 1
   AND y.ym = DATE_FORMAT('2018-01-02','%Y-%m')
 WHERE y.user_id IS NULL
 LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | date       |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2018-01-01 |
|  2 |       1 | 2018-01-02 |
|  3 |       1 | 2018-01-02 |
+----+---------+------------+

INSERT INTO my_table (user_id,date)
SELECT 1
     , '2018-01-03'
  FROM (SELECT 1) x
  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT user_id
             , DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') ym
          FROM my_table
         GROUP
            BY user_id
             , ym
        HAVING COUNT(*) >=3
       ) y
    ON y.user_id = 1
   AND y.ym = DATE_FORMAT('2018-01-03','%Y-%m')
 WHERE y.user_id IS NULL
 LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | date       |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2018-01-01 |
|  2 |       1 | 2018-01-02 |
|  3 |       1 | 2018-01-02 |
+----+---------+------------+

INSERT INTO my_table (user_id,date)
SELECT 1
     , '2018-02-03'
  FROM (SELECT 1) x
  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT user_id
             , DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') ym
          FROM my_table
         GROUP
            BY user_id
             , ym
        HAVING COUNT(*) >=3
       ) y
    ON y.user_id = 1
   AND y.ym = DATE_FORMAT('2018-02-03','%Y-%m')
 WHERE y.user_id IS NULL
 LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | date       |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2018-01-01 |
|  2 |       1 | 2018-01-02 |
|  3 |       1 | 2018-01-02 |
|  4 |       1 | 2018-02-03 |
+----+---------+------------+
```

Comment: I don't get it. Can you please solve it using my code.