# How can create a variable that store the value and pass in strtotime in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer

How can create a variable and store some value and pass to strtotime function?

like:

```
$date='2018-12-19'; 
$time='12:00:00';
```

Two variables are created and define the values.

now

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    p {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 60px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    // 1. JavaScript
    // var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();
    // 2. PHP
    <?php 

    ?>
    var countDownDate = <?php 

    $date='2018-12-19'; //variable and value define
    $time='12:00:00'; 

    echo strtotime('$date $time') ?> * 1000;///there is an error nothing show . 
    var now = <?php echo time() ?> * 1000;

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

        // Get todays date and time
        // 1. JavaScript
        // var now = new Date().getTime();
        // 2. PHP
        now = now + 1000;

        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
            minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

        // If the count down is over, write some text 
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        }
    }, 1000);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have defined the variable and values. But when run the PHP code the counter timer does not visible.

How can create variable and pass values? I want to create a dynamic counter timer.

Comment: `strtotime('$date $time')` won't work because it will pass the literal string `'$date $time` - that exact sequence of characters - into the function. You should use double quotes instead.

Comment: oh, and Javascript has full functionality for working with dates and times. I don't see anything here which actually needs PHP.

Comment: Exually I want to create a database date and for  time and fetch the value from the database and store in variable $date and $time and then pass into storytime .But i don't know how to do? ..

Comment: ok fair enough, you'll need a backend language to fetch data from the database. But see the other answers for how to fix the code - including my first comment above (same as @CarlosFdev's answer), just use double quotes instead of single.

Comment: Right. It solved by double quotes...Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use dot concatenations you could just swap your single quotes to double quotes

```
strtotime("$date $time")
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is concatenate the date with the time.

```
$date='2018-12-19'; //variable and value define
$time='12:00:00'; 

echo strtotime($date . ' ' . $time);
```

This will output:

```
1545249600
```

As @Robin Zigmond pointed out in the comment above, there is no reason not use a JS solution for this.  That way you do not have to break in and out of PHP.

I would recommend us a JS library called [Moment](https://momentjs.com/).  All you have to do is hotlink to the library like so:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Then in your code all you would have to do is something like this:

```
var dateString ='2018-12-19'; 
var timeString ='12:00:00'; 
var timeStamp = (moment(dateString + ' ' +  timeString).unix())*1000;
```

The Moment library is very nice.  I use it alot.  A good thing to have in your toolbox.

Comment: Its an error after use your solution -----error --->>>
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' ) ?> * 1000; ' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ex\main.php on line 30`

Comment: You may need to refresh your browser.. I accidentally left a single quote in the strtotime function.  The code as I have it written works.

Comment: Hello Joseph can you answer it .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52492121/how-to-restrict-user-to-upload-only-three-images-in-a-month-using-php-mysql

Comment: As far as your other question, I think you should use @fabrik approach.  Very simple and effective approach.