# How can I limit the max value of number in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, max, vote

I've been creating a voting system and I've noticed that the users are still able to vote again after logout.
What I'm trying to do is to add a variable to vote, now button, and set its maximum value to 1 to prevent the user from voting again.

Is there any suggestion or way to achieve this so users will not be able to vote again like?

```
$errors = array(); 
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registration");
if (isset($_POST['votenow'])) {
    $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE votenow = '$votenow'";
    $votenow = "update users set votenow = votenow + 1";
    $run_vote = mysqli_query($db, $votenow);
    if ($votenow > 1 ) {
        echo "No more votes can be added.";
    } 
    if ($run_vote) { 
        header( "Location: renewsys3.php" ); 
    } 
}
```

I've been also trying this but the users can still vote again. The votes were working that limits to 1 vote but the users are still being redirect to next page instead of returning. renewsys2re is the current page and renewsys3 is the next page.

```
<?php
$errors = array(); 
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","registration");

    if(isset($_POST['votenow']))
    { 

    $votenow = "update users set votenow = votenow + 1 where votenow < 1 
    LIMIT 1";

    $run_vote = mysqli_query($db,$votenow);

    if ($votenow == 2 ){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Once!");</script>';
    header ("Refresh:0; url=renewsys2re.php");
    }

    else{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Welcome!");</script>';
    header ("Refresh:0; url=renewsys3.php");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: Why doesn't your code do what you want?

Comment: E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52492121/how-to-restrict-user-to-upload-only-three-images-in-a-month-using-php-mysql/52503572#52503572

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain $_SESSION variable after user login and logout.You have to store and compare `user_id` and modified your query of checking votes to 
`$user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id and votenow=:votenow";`

Use [bindparams](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) to add security from sql injection.